# Negative Lookahead with Regex to exclude phrases containing a particular word in Google Analytics and Google Search Console

Tags: regex, google-analytics, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-negation

Recently Google launched a new feature on Google Search Console - Regex for queries.

I would like to exclude input that contains any of a list of keywords.

With `[^test one|test2]`, I can exclude exact match.

I would like to find out how I can exclude all the phrases (strings) containing `"test one"` or `"test2"`:

Here is a list of inputs and expected match:

| input | should match? |
| --- | --- |
| `test one goes ok` | no |
| `test2` | no |
| `tomorrow` | yes |
| `test one` | no |
| `test2 tomorrow` | no |
| `goes ok` | yes |

This is going to be implemented on Google Search Console according to the [guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7576553/#regex_filter&zippy=):

Regular expression filter
If you choose the Custom (regex) filter, you can filter by a regular expression (a wildcard match) for the selected item. You can use regular expression filters for page URLs and user queries. The RE2 syntax is used.

The default matching is "partial match", which means that your regular expression can match anywhere in the target string unless you use ^ or $ to require matching from the start or end of the string, respectively.
Default matching is case-sensitive. You can specify "(?i)" at the beginning of your regular expression string for case-insensitive matches. Example: (?i)https
Invalid regular expression syntax will return no matches.
Regular expression matching is tricky; try out your expression on a live testing tool, or read the full RE2 syntax guide

Comment: Did you mean *"test one" **or** "test2"*? Also, please indicate which of your sample inputs should match and which should not match.

Comment: 1. both. I would like to include to the regex a list of words to exclude.

Comment: 2. I expect that with the regex exclusion I will get only the following list: tomorrow, goes ok. The rest of the keywords will be excluded.

Comment: Now regex exclusion of multiple words works perfectly in g console. Try this: https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2021/06/regex-negative-match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative look ahead to *exclude* input with any of your blacklist terms:

```
^(?!.*(test one|test2)).*
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/QS2yLd37RdacfP).

Comment: thank you! Unfortunately, it does not work in Google Search Console. I found the guidelines https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7576553/#regex_filter&zippy=, could it be that they set up something specifical?

Comment: @Hanna google doesn't support look arounds. Without them you can't do it, unless you reverse the condition and require input to *not* match `^.*(test one|test2).*$` like an *exclusion* regex instead of a *filter* regex.

Comment: thank you for your reply! does it mean there is no way for me to filter the list of keywords and remove the strings/phrases containing test one or test2? With ^.*(test one|test2).*$ I am getting only a list of keywords containing test one and test2.

Comment: @hanna yes - there may be a way to specify an excluding regex, rather than in including regex. I am not familiar with the tool you’re using

Answer (score 0):

Simply just write:
`test one|test2`

Make sure in the filter dropdown is selected: "Custom (regex)"

Helper material: https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2021/06/regex-negative-match